# How to activate function with multiple ways?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function right now that is only called at `window.onload()`, but I also want it to be called when I click on a button, without copying the same code.

```
window.onload = function testConnectie(){

$('#fresh').one('click', function(){
```

I need the function `testConnectie` to be called at `window.onload()` and when that button with fresh is clicked.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a separate function and call the same in both the cases:

```js
function testConnectie() {
    alert('connected')
};

window.onload = testConnectie;

$('#fresh').one('click', testConnectie);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fresh">Fresh</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

one way to do it is asigning the function to a variable for example:

```
var testConnectie = function (){
   console.log("test")
}

window.onload = testConnectie;

$('#fresh').one('click', testConnectie);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the callback function and pass the Event Object (even if you don't use it explicitly).
2. Register the Window Object to the old school on-event property `.onload`.
3. Next, delegate the 'click' event using the jQuery `.on()` method (`.one()` method only allows the button to be clicked once...not sure why it's in the OP).
4. **Note:** both invocation of `testConnect()` ***does not*** have the parenthesis at the end of their names. The reason why is because the triggered event determines when the callback fires, otherwise if the parenthesis were to be present, the function would fire as soon as the browser reads it.
5. The callback `testConnect()` will change the text of the button to the event type. So it will be "load" and when clicked it will be "click".

```css
.test {
  font: 700 32px/1.2 Arial;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgba(51, 50, 30, 0.2);
  border: 3px ridge #333;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  color: #998;
}
```

```html
<a href='#/' class='test'>TEST</a>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  window.onload = testConnect;

  $('.test').on('click', testConnect);

  function testConnect(event) {
    var evt = event.type;
    console.log(evt);
    $('.test').text(evt);
  }
</script>
```